# Javascript Object Assignment gottcha

Tags: javascript, object, assignment-operator

I came across this whilst building sort buttons for a data table. I wanted to have each sort button to toggle between a DESC (sort down) and ASC (sort up) and inactive - the default sort.

So I created two models one was going to be the one that changed as the program progressed and one was a default to reset the values

```js
var model = {
  order: {
    field: 'creationDate',
    direction: 'DESC'
  },
  orderDefault: {
    field: 'creationDate',
    direction: 'DESC'
  }
}

$('button').click(function() {
  if (model.order.field == "creationDate") {
    model.order.field = 'newField'
  } else if (model.order.direction == 'DESC') {
    model.order.direction = 'ASC'
  } else {
// This casuses the orderDefault object to be a clone of the order object
// so assignment of values in model.order are refelected in model.orderDefault GOTCHA!!!!
    model.order = model.orderDefault
  }
  $('#result').html('field:' + model.order.field + " direction:" + model.order.direction);
}
)
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary">
  click me
</button>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

So you will see that it all works as expected until the point where we reset the order object. the second time we get to this point in the code you will see that it never resets. It seems that the orderDefault obj becomes an alias of order obj.

Comment: This is because objects are assigned by reference in JavaScript, i.e. they are not copied upon assignment. It is a very common behavior among popular programming languages, as far as I known.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that instead of assigning orderDefault you need to assign the values of orderDefault

so NOT

```
model.order = model.orderDefault
```

BUT

```
 model.order.direction = model.orderDefault.direction
 model.order.field = model.orderDefault.field
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: If your platform supports it, you can use `Object.assign(model.order, model.orderDefault)`.

Comment: Yes I hadn't seen that, thanks and there is a polyfill for older browsers so that looks like a good solution. What I found interesting is that the assignment using '=' wasn't actually an assignment but an assertion of equivalence. So if you changed  property x in object A then that would change property x in object B.

Comment: It is actually an assignment of the reference to the object, instead of the value of the object. `model.order = model.orderDefault` means "the *name* `model.order` now *points to* the *value* of `model.orderDefault`" so both names now point to the same object There is no A and B after that, only A. Java, Python and many other languages behave the same.